# Transforming GCS_OSGB_1936 to WGS_1984_UTM

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.3, coordinate-system

I am trying to add a DEM data layer to my map in ArcGIS 10.3.

The options available to transform the coordinate system to are:  WGS_1984_1,  WGS_1984_2,  WGS_1984_3,  WGS_1984_4,  WGS_1984_8.

Which one should I select?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Depends of which area represents your DEM. Check [Geographic (datum) transformations, parameters and areas of use](http://help.arcgis.com/es/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/003r/pdf/geographic_transformations.pdf). They have small differences in *dy* and *dz* translation.

Areas are:

```
OSGB_1936_To_WGS_1984_1             UK - England, Scotland, Wales, and Isle of Man UK - England
OSGB_1936_To_WGS_1984_2             UK - England
OSGB_1936_To_WGS_1984_3             UK - England, Wales, and Isle of Man
OSGB_1936_To_WGS_1984_4             UK - Scotland, including Shetland Islands
OSGB_1936_To_WGS_1984_5             UK - Wales
OSGB_1936_To_WGS_1984_Petroleum     UK - England, Scotland, Wales, N Sea
```

By the way, I don't recommend you to reproject a DEM to geographic coordinates system, is better to work in your DEM's CRS and reproject other files, such vectors or raster with discrete values.